# How to get entries with datetime less than an ISO String

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with the an entry:

```
======================================================
id |       start_date        |       end_date
------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2019-04-17 00:00:00.000 | 2019-04-18 10:30:00.000
======================================================
```

I am trying to use the following query to get this entry:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE end_date > '2019-04-17T17:19:47Z' AND end_date <= '2019-04-17T10:31:46Z'
```

but it is not returning the entry. If I just do

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE end_date > '2019-04-17T17:19:47Z'
```

I can get the row, but not when I add the second <= comparison. What am I doing wrong and how can I get the entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like your second date is earlier than the first one. Which mean that no date can be greater than `2019-04-17T17:19:47Z` AND less than or equal to `2019-04-17T10:31:46Z`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that.

Comment: No worries. Sometimes we all need a second pair of eyes :)